# Converting complicated SQL statement to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following sql statement, which works perfect and since I'm transferring everything to PDO, I've having the worst time trying to convert this complicated statement. Here it is working below:

```
$sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.uid, a.hometown, 
IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend FROM users a LEFT JOIN friends 
b ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = $uid WHERE  
CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) LIKE '%$q%' AND a.uid <> $uid 
ORDER BY isFriend DESC");
```

I've been trying for hours to convert and this is all I could get from another S.O example (it's not even close to working)

Any help is wonderfully appreciate. Oh and also $q is a POST variable from the user so PDO is a must in my case.

UPDATED Code (2nd time):

```
$sql = "select a.first_name, a.last_name, a.uid, a.hometown, 
IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend FROM users a LEFT JOIN 
friends b ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = :friend_one 
where ( first_name like concat('%', :fname, '%') or last_name like 
concat('%', :lname, '%') ) and a.uid <> :uid ORDER BY isFriend DESC"; 
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->bindValue(':fname', "%$q%", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindValue(':lname', "%$q%", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute(array(':friend_one' => $uid,':uid' => $uid));
```

**This works without any error but fails to produce the same results as the original sql statement.**

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: @Marc B: PDO can be tricky to debug as you can't always see the errors returned

Comment: pdo errno and errcode not enough? I'd agree it's difficult if those aren't saying anything, but not even checking them is just lazy...

Comment: the missing `.` behind your `WHERE` is just a copy paste error, or is it in you php code to?

Comment: you also have 2x `from users`

Comment: seems like your conversion of CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) LIKE '%$q%' AND a.uid <> $uid  should be simply CONCAT(a.first_name, '  ', a.last_name) LIKE '%:fname :lname%' AND a.uid <> $uid but it is hard to tell as you haven't described $q (the spaces don't show in this comment for some reason it just shows'')

Comment: @MarcB Updated example with error. Puggan, I added the missing . and still getting error. Also sdjaun, this is just a live search app that searches for users based on the user's input.

Comment: Hey @MarcB Any idea why the following, which works without errors, won't return the same results as my original query?

Comment: $sql = "select
a.first_name,
a.last_name,
a.uid,
a.hometown,
IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend 
FROM users a 
LEFT JOIN friends b
ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = :friend_one
where 
(
first_name like concat('%', :fname, '%') or 
last_name  like concat('%', :lname, '%') 
) and
a.uid <> :uid
ORDER BY
isFriend DESC";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':fname', "%$q%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':lname', "%$q%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array(':friend_one' => $uid,':uid' => $uid));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the extra `from` and put `()` around your name filter, as
`A OR B AND C` = `A OR (B AND C)`, and i gues you wanted `(A OR) B AND C`

```
select
  a.first_name,
  a.last_name,
  a.uid,
  a.hometown,
  IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend 
FROM users a 
LEFT JOIN friends b
  ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = :uid
where 
  (
    first_name like concat('%', :fname, '%') or 
    last_name  like concat('%', :lname, '%') 
  ) and
  a.uid <> :uid 
ORDER BY
  isFriend DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Puggan. This is my code and it's so close $sql = "select
a.first_name,
a.last_name,
a.uid,
a.hometown,
IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend 
FROM users a 
LEFT JOIN friends b
ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = :uid
where 
(
first_name like concat('%', :fname, '%') or 
last_name  like concat('%', :lname, '%') 
) and
a.uid <> '1' 
ORDER BY
isFriend DESC";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':fname', '%$q%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':lname', '%$q%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));

Comment: But I end up getting the error, "Mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given". I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ?, `mysql_fetch_array()` is not a PDO function

Comment: Sorry, I meant  while($row = $stmt->fetch()){...
I got it to work without error but it seems that it's reading the CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) function differently than before because now, I don't get any of the results back. Everything runs without errors but no results sadly.

Comment: you concating % to the :fname, so you don't need % in the bind statement to `bindValue(':fname', "%$q%"`